# Npm package upgrade notification availlable?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, software-distribution

I wrote a node package which contains breaking changes in the next release. Does there exist a way to notify developers about that via console while upgrading via npm?

Comment: Are you using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)?

Comment: Yes. I think this is a prerequisite for package.json at npm.

Comment: So why not just incrementing the major component of the version number?

Comment: The question is: How to notify developers about breaking changes via console text while upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution to inform the via console, but if your new version is given by an new "major" number, it should not break the code.

**Breaking example**

- Client dependency: ~1.2.2
- Your old version: 1.2.2
- Your new version: 1.**2**.3

The client will upgrade to version 1.2.3.

**Not breaking example**

- User dependency: ~1.2.2
- Your old version: 1.2.2
- Your new version: 1.**3**.0

The client will not upgrade.